# Issue with the If statement when executing an SQL Statement - c#

Tags: c#, sql, if-statement

i have made a form in c# to add data into my datatable, it works fine, all i want is to return a message when the data is inserted, and i am having an issue with that, the code is as follows:

```
conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = ("INSERT INTO datatable (Number_Plate,Registered_Keeper,Make,Model,Year_Of_Make,Colour,Engine_Size,Transmission,Fuel_Type) Values (@Number_Plate,@Registered_Keeper,@Make,@Model,@Year_Of_Make,@Colour,@Engine_Size,@Transmission,@Fuel_Type)");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number_Plate", Plate.Text); 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Registered_Keeper", Keeper.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Make", Make.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", Model.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year_Of_Make", Year.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Colour", Colour.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Engine_Size", Engine.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transmission", Transmission.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fuel_Type", Fuel.Text);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()==1)
            {
                button1.Visible = false;
                label10.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                button1.Visible = false;
                label10.Text = "Data Not Added Please try Again!";
                label10.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

when i run the code, i get an issue with the If statement ane the error is:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

any help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have `SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();` in there? That doesn't make any sense... and the error is telling you exactly that.

Comment: Please read up on the [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.110).aspx).  `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, and `SqlDataReader` (though you don't need it here) all implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove this line (*you don't need it*)

```
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

makes no sense because you are inserting a record and not fetching on the database.

snippet,

```
        // other codes
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Engine_Size", Engine.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Transmission", Transmission.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fuel_Type", Fuel.Text);
        if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()==1)
        {
            button1.Visible = false;
        // other codes
```

Comment: i have tried that code and it is displaying the label but not inserting the data into the data table

Answer (score 0):

You have open Connection to Database previously. So you need to close that first to execute.

```
conn.close()
```